# Python cannot find module Request from urllib.request

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Python cannot find module Request from urllib.request

**update:** - well i try to run this with python3.... see:

```
martin@linux-3645:~/dev/python> Python3 w9.py
If 'Python3' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this:
    cnf Python3
martin@linux-3645:~/dev/python>
```

When trying to import Request from urllib.request in a Python-code, it's unable to find the package.

```
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named request
```

see the code i am trying to run...:

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = "https://wordpress.org/plugins/participants-database/"
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

ttt = page_soup.find("div", {"class":"plugin-meta"})
text_nodes = [node.text.strip() for node in ttt.ul.findChildren('li')[:-1:2]]
```

unfortunatly this results in:

```
martin@linux-3645:~/dev/python> python w9.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "w9.py", line 3, in <module>
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
ImportError: No module named request
martin@linux-3645:~/dev/python>
```

Well: there is no urllib.request module in Python 2, that module only exists in Python 3.

i did some search and found a possible fix: see this **soultion:** i could use urllib2 instead:

```
from urllib2 import Request
```

**From the top of the module documentation:**
Note: The urllib2 module has been split across several modules in Python 3 named urllib.request and urllib.error. The 2to3 tool will automatically adapt imports when converting your sources to Python 3.

**But  wait**: i thought that i allready run Python 3 and that i continue to use that version; the code i am trying to execute is clearly designed for Python 3.

what goes wrong here?

Comment: Are you sure you're running Python 3 with the command `python w9.py`?

Comment: Just so you know: yes, this is the expected error you would get if you're trying to run this with Python 2.x

Comment: Maybe add a shebang or invoke with `python3`

Comment: hello dear all - many thanks for the quick reply; see the update in the posting. I added the comand and the reply....I am actually not sure what goes wrong there... . Look forward to hear from you

Comment: lowercase p when running python3

Comment: with lowercae pythion3  now  i t gives gack no results at all -- further tests later the evening - i have to leave office now - unfortunatley

Comment: Just `python3` not `pythion3`

Comment: If you ran python3 and didn't get any errors, your code worked! Your sample code doesn't produce any output, therefore, no result is a good result. Add print(text_nodes) and you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample code is for python3. Please note that you must run "python3" in lowercase, not Python3.

With the sample code you have posted, you won't get any output on screen because you have not asked for any output.

If you add `print(text_nodes)` at the end, you will get the following output:

> ['Version: 1.7.7.7', 'Active installations: 10,000+', 'Tested up to:
>   4.9.4']